# Explaining greatest common divisor using recursion in JAVA

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to understand recursion better. If I am understanding this correctly, recursion works with your base cases and simpler versions of the original case. So normally one will see code subtracting one from a parameter. However, I saw the following code and I don't understand how it is working without the simplification of cases. Any explanation will be helpful.

```
public static long gcd(long a, long b) {

   if (b==0) 
     return a;
   else
     return gcd(b, a % b);
 }
```

Comment: `b` will be smaller and smaller because of module http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm

Comment: `a % b` makes the second argument smaller each call, until `b == 0` when there is no remainder; and you're done.

Comment: @BoristheSpider So with real numbers like a =8 and b = 12 it will look like gcd(12, 8%12) then next step gcd(8%12, 8 %(8%12)) and so on?

Comment: @Rika see below. I have worked out your example with a=8 and b=12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This particular example is using the [Euclidean algorithm](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~greenfie/gs2004/euclid.html).  It states that you can find the gcd of the value by taking the second number and making it the first, and taking the remainder of a/b to get the second.  You continue doing this until the second number reaches 0.

Example
`gcd(2,8)`

```
a=2
b=8
a%b=2
```

So the next call is `gcd(8,2)`

```
a=8
b=2
a%b=0 (since 8/2=4)
```

So it would call gcd one remaining time `gcd(2,0)`

```
a=2
b=0
```

It would reach the base case of `b==0` and return `a=2`.

Comment: Thank you this was helpful. Before I read this, I was always keeping 'a' the same, but I get what I was doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way for me to understand recursion to build a recursion tree with a few examples

---

gcd(10,20) ------------------- **output:** finally 10 is returned here.
    |
gcd(20, 10)------------------- **output:** Since nothing else happens to the output, 10 is propagation up here and returned to the above statement.
    |
***gcd(10, 0)*** ------------------- **output:** This is the base case, where 10 is returned.

---

gcd(4,5)------------------- **output:** finally 1 is returned here.
    |
gcd(5, 4)------------------- **output:** same thing as below, 1 is propagated back up the execution chain
    |
gcd(4, 1)------------------- **output:** Since nothing else happens to the output, 1 is propagation up here and returned to the above statement.
    |
***gcd(1, 0)***-------------------**output:** This is the base case, where 1 is returned.

---

gcd(8,12)------------------- **output:** finally 4 is returned here.
    |
gcd(12, 8)------------------- **output:** same thing as below, 4 is propagated back up the execution chain
    |
gcd(8, 4)------------------- **output:** Since nothing else happens to the output, 4 is propagation up here and returned to the above statement.
    |
***gcd(4, 0)***-------------------**output:** This is the base case, where 4 is returned.

---

Running through examples like these helps me understand the recursive recurrence relations, which presents the nature of the recursive method.

**NOTE**: Sorry for the horrible formatting on the trees. I'm not a SO expert and don't know of a way to make these "trees" look better.

Answer (score 0):

I seriously don't understand what do you mean by the simplification of cases but let me try to explain what's happening there.
You base case is:
if (b==0) 
return a;

Generally, when we talk about recursion first thing we need to do is find the base case.
Well, a gcd of a number and a 0 is always the number (Our base case).

Next we need to say what % does. 5%10 = 5 and 10%5=0. So lets take an example.
gcd(5,10)

1. gcd(10, 5%10) = gcd(10,5)
2. gcd(5, 10%5) = gcd(5,0)
3. When it reaches the third recursion, it hits the base class and returns 5.

We can make the base case as 
if(a==0||b==0)
return a+b;

So when you say return gcd(a,b), the method starts again and does it's job until it returns a long.

HIH.
Thanks